# React Mapbox Extra Button Doesnt Work Inside Popup

Tags: reactjs, button, mapbox

I am working with mapbox react gl - It is working pretty nice so far... except one thing.
The user can add their hometown location to the map. When the hometown location appears, it can be clicked to view a popup. I want the user to be able to remove the location from the map from inside the popup - So I added a function that removes the location from the database when a button is clicked. The problem is when the button is inside the popup the function doesn't fire - and I have no idea why.

I have messed with the z index of the button but it seems like whenever the button is clicked, the onClose function is being called instead of my handleDeleteHome function...

Edit* If I remove the onClose function, the handleDeleteHome function fires.

Any help is appriciated! Thanks!

```
{selectedHome && (
                            <Popup 
                                latitude={bandLocation[0]} 
                                longitude={bandLocation[1]}
                                onClose={() => {setSelectedHome(null)}}
                                offsetLeft={23}
                                offsetTop={-10}
                                >
                                    <div>
                                        <h4>Home Town</h4>
                                        <Button 
                                            onClick={(e) => {
                                            e.preventDefault()
                                            handleDeleteHome()
                                        }} 
                                        color="danger">x</Button>
                                    </div>
                            </Popup>
                        )}
```

Answer (score 2):

Alright! Figured it out - If anyone else needs to know:
You need to add closeOnClick={false} to the popup!